# How do you change rank of tf.random_normal as a shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, traceback

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm following a tutorial by sentdex.
No matter how many syntax issues I resolve, I keep on getting the same error.

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 
'random_normal_7/RandomStandardNormal' (op: 'RandomStandardNormal') 
with input shapes: []
```

I believe the issue is here, but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
def neural_network_model(data):
hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 
n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'biases': 
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, 
n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases': 
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, 
n_nodes_hl3])),
                  'biases': 
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, 
n_classes])),
                'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_classes))}
```

My entire code is

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/ data/", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')


def neural_network_model(data):
hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 
n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'biases': 
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, 
n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases': 
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, 
n_nodes_hl3])),
                  'biases': 
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, 
n_classes])),
                'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_classes))}

l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), 
hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights']), 
hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_3_layer['weights']), 
hidden_3_layer['biases'])
l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + 
output_layer['biases']

return output


def train_neural_network(x):
prediction = neural_network_model(x)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
(logits=prediction, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

hm_epochs = 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
            epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x,
y: epoch_y})
            epoch_loss += c
        print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', 
epoch_loss)

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: 
mnist.test.labels}))


train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: did you try `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])` in your output_layer biases? it seems to be missing the brackets in your code

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to [`tf.random_normal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) (the `shape`) must be a one-dimensional tensor or a list of integers, representing length of each dimension of the random tensor. Assuming that `n_classes` is an integer, replacing `tf.random_normal(n_classes)` with `tf.random_normal([n_classes])` should fix the error.

Comment: That definitely resolved the error. But a new one has come up. Instead of an issue with the rank, I'm getting one with dimensions. The error is    "ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 784 and 500 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,784], [500,500]."

Comment: I think the problem is that one this line: `l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights'])`, you're multiplying `data` by the weights of layer 2, but instead you should be multiplying `l1` by the weights of layer 2 (the definition of layer 3 has the same bug).

Comment: I don't believe that is the issue. Instead, I replaced the layers "," between the weights and biases with a plus sign. The giant traceback issue was solved. Now I'm getting a type error: l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']) + hidden_1_layer['biases'])
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Answer (score 0):

you must make connection from Layer 1 to Layer 2, seems like you passing data to all the layer without connecting them, 
your code

```
l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), 
hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_2_layer['weights']), 
hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_3_layer['weights']), 
hidden_3_layer['biases'])
l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + 
output_layer['biases']
```

Corrected code:

```
l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), 
hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), 
hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), 
hidden_3_layer['biases'])
l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + 
output_layer['biases']
```